# Angular4 and TypeScript property does not exist on type any[]

Tags: angular, typescript

I can't seem to figure this thing out... I'm getting data from an api and storing it as any[]. I'm trying to get data like this...

```
this.data.results[i].datas[j].dataType
```

But I get the error property results does not exist on type any[]. I've tried looking at many other questions and answers but I can't seem to figure it out.

(Should I just create a data object and instead of assigning the data to any[], assign it to the object?)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please put more code in order to help you ?

Comment: And the exact and full error message. Also add what printing the value `console.log(...)` returns exactly. You are mentioning `any[]`, but your code doesn't show how you're using it.

Comment: Are you getting a typescript compilation error or a runtime error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the type definition of `this.data` to:

```
data: {results?: any[]} = {};
```

Comment: @PierreDuc I have a dynamic form and don't know any form control while compilation, at compilation time I get for ex:Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'. any solutions for this type of forms?, and I only get this error while compiling with `aot`

Comment: change the typing of your data to `any`, or change it to `{name?: string}`

Answer (score 1):

I'd always (when possible) at least declare an interface like this:

```
interface IDataset {
    dataType: string;
    value: string;
    // Whatevery your dataset holds
}

interface IResultset {
    datas: IDataset[9]
}

interface IData {
    results: IResultset[];
}

class SomeClass {
    data: IData[];

    someFunction() {
        this.data.results[i].datas[j].dataType = "whatever";
    }
}
```

That way you get IntelliSense for your data, have to structure your data in a way that makes sense and could use these interfaces on both client and server side (if you are working on the server too)

Comment: Yeah I know, I really should just declare the object/interface. But my stubbornness kicked in and I wanted to fix it this way :P now that I did it this way I'll create the object haha, I just wanted the feeling of victory